# Code is not delievered by SendCodeRequest without error and this happens only on server-side with Heroku

Tags: heroku, telegram, telethon

Here is my situation:  the same Telethon code is used on my local machine and on the server. Requesting authorization code from local machine works fine. Requesting the code from the server does not produce any error, and code is not sent. Sometimes it works even from the server without any changes in code.

I suppose there might be some ip blocks or something related to the ip, cause that is the only thing which might differ on the server side:  Heroku assign ip addresses dynamically, so, there might by some subnets which are blocked by Telegram API for some reason. But there is no error and that is really strange. There are too many ip addresses to disprove the hypothesis. I need to catch at least one ip address which gives me opposite results: one time code it recieved and another time does not. So I am stuck with this situation and have no ideas how it could be fixed or clarified.

```
global t
t = None


async def ssssendCode(phone):
    global t
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(phone+'.session'):
            logger.debug('client file exists')
        else:
            logger.debug('client file does not exist')
        if t is None:
            t = TelegramClient(phone, settings['telegramClientAPIId'], settings['telegramClientAPIHash'])
        t.phone = phone
        #t.phone_code_hash = None
        await t.connect()
        #response = await t.send_code_request(phone=phone,force_sms=True)
        s3_session.resource('s3').Bucket('telethon').upload_file(str(phone)+".session", str(phone)+".session")
        logger.debug(str(requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip').text))
        response = await t.send_code_request(phone=phone)
        logger.debug(str(t.is_connected()))
    except Exception as e:
        response = str(e)

    return str(response)
```

example of response to the local machine request

```
SentCode(type=SentCodeTypeSms(length=5), phone_code_hash='b5b069a2a4122040f1', next_type=CodeTypeCall(), timeout=120)
```

example of reponse to the server-side request

```
SentCode(type=SentCodeTypeSms(length=5), phone_code_hash='0e89db0324c1af0149', next_type=CodeTypeCall(), timeout=120)
```

send_code_request is the from the Telethon without modifications

```
async def send_code_request(
            self: 'TelegramClient',
            phone: str,
            *,
            force_sms: bool = False) -> 'types.auth.SentCode':
        """
        Sends the Telegram code needed to login to the given phone number.

        Arguments
            phone (`str` | `int`):
                The phone to which the code will be sent.

            force_sms (`bool`, optional):
                Whether to force sending as SMS.

        Returns
            An instance of :tl:`SentCode`.

        Example
            .. code-block:: python

                phone = '+34 123 123 123'
                sent = await client.send_code_request(phone)
                print(sent)
        """
        result = None
        phone = utils.parse_phone(phone) or self._phone
        phone_hash = self._phone_code_hash.get(phone)

        if not phone_hash:
            try:
                result = await self(functions.auth.SendCodeRequest(
                    phone, self.api_id, self.api_hash, types.CodeSettings()))
            except errors.AuthRestartError:
                return await self.send_code_request(phone, force_sms=force_sms)

            # If we already sent a SMS, do not resend the code (hash may be empty)
            if isinstance(result.type, types.auth.SentCodeTypeSms):
                force_sms = False

            # phone_code_hash may be empty, if it is, do not save it (#1283)
            if result.phone_code_hash:
                self._phone_code_hash[phone] = phone_hash = result.phone_code_hash
        else:
            force_sms = True

        self._phone = phone

        if force_sms:
            result = await self(
                functions.auth.ResendCodeRequest(phone, phone_hash))

            self._phone_code_hash[phone] = result.phone_code_hash

        return result
```

Just in case: I have much more than 2 minutes between attempts to get a code from the local machine and server, so it is absolutely not the timeout issue. And moreover: even when requesting the code from the local right after half a minute from the failed server-side attemp: code is coming almost immediately.

Comment: The weirdest thing is you're able to see the `SentCode` response on the server, so that has me puzzled. Honestly, I would just use a `StringSession` described in the docs and login locally.

Comment: This problem seems to be related to AWS